# Proximity alert firing twice after removing and re-adding

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am having a problem with the proximity alert. I have settings on my android application where users can disable/enable proximity alert of some locations. When they disable the proximity alert everything works great and they will not be notified, but if they disable and the re-enable the proximity alert, it adds again and they will get a notification twice when they reach a location and so on. So basically every time they re-enable it, it creates a new proximity alert.

This is the code I use to remove the proximity alert:

```
private void removeProximityAlert(int id) {
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT + id);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    manager.removeProximityAlert(proximityIntent);
}
```

And this is the code that I use to add a proximity alert:

```
private void addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, int id, int radius, String title) {
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT + id);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    manager.addProximityAlert(
           latitude,
           longitude,
           radius,
           -1,
           proximityIntent
    );

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT + id);
    registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(id, title), filter);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();`? Adding cancel should "Cancel a currently active PendingIntent. Only the original application owning a PendingIntent can cancel it."

Comment: `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` will return the existing `PendingIntent` and `cancel()` will do as it is named.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` is that it tells the system that the old pending intent is no longer valid and it should cancel it and then create a fresh one. Correct me if I am wrong. This, I believe, is why you are duplicating Proximity Alerts with each cancel and creation.

**Resolution:**

In your `removeProximityAlert` I would change the following line

```
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

to:

```
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
```

`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` returns the existing one created, if any. `cancel()` should take care of the rest for you.

---

**Edit**

If I break the `cancel()` into a separate line I don't get any errors. Try this:

```
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
proximityIntent.cancel();
```

Comment: When I use cancel() it gives me an error to that line: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to PendingIntent"

Comment: @edoniti, Yeah sry I got the same error when I tried. See edit above.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working. When I set the proximityalert checkbox on settings to "Off" it works great so it does not notify you when you reach a location, but when I re-enable it it notifies two times. If I uninstall the app and then install it again it works great until I change the proximityalert settings on my app. For example if I disable/enable 4 times the settings, I will get 5 proximityalert notifications.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're registering the receiver each time you add the alarm. You should register it only once.